Create pandas time series DataFrame using hypothesis
I need to create a pd.DataFrame with a datetime or pd.date_range index. I have the following code, which almost generates what I need.
However, a time series index is characterized by the fact that you have increasing dates/times. My code fails on this point.
import datetime

from hypothesis import strategies as st
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns as cols
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import data_frames, indexes


data_frames(
    columns=cols(
        ["sec1", "sec2", "sec3"], elements=st.floats(allow_infinity=False)
    ),
    index=indexes(
        elements=st.dates(
            min_value=datetime.date(2023, 10, 31),
            max_value=datetime.date(2024, 5, 31),
        ),
        min_size=5,
    ),
).example()
Out[56]: 
                     sec1           sec2          sec3
2024-01-06  -1.000000e-05  2.225074e-313 -6.293733e+16
2023-10-31  1.797693e+308  -4.344429e+16  1.401298e-45
2024-03-26            NaN -1.112537e-308  1.500000e+00
2023-11-26   1.000000e-05   2.220446e-16 -1.000000e-05
2023-11-13   1.900000e+00 -1.112537e-308  0.000000e+00
2024-03-14  6.607726e-296            NaN -3.333333e-01
2023-12-19 -1.346975e+185  -2.664620e+16 -2.568750e+16
2024-02-02   1.000000e-05   5.911449e+16           NaN
2024-05-03  1.112537e-308  6.984170e-302 -5.000000e-01
2024-01-12   5.000000e-01  -1.175494e-38           NaN

I am wondering if it is possible to replace my indexes(...) code with something along those lines:
pd.date_range(start="12-29-2023", periods=10, freq="B", name="date")


If I understood you right, if you are creating a new column from the date_range and then setting is as index: set_index?

Yes, something like this. I just need to make sure to generate a datetime index that is increasing in nature. In my example this is not the case. Some dates are decreasing.

You can do this approach:
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from hypothesis import strategies as st
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import columns as cols
from hypothesis.extra.pandas import data_frames, indexes

date_index = pd.date_range(start="2023-12-29", periods=10, freq="B").tolist()

df_strategy = data_frames(
    columns=cols(
        ["sec1", "sec2", "sec3"], elements=st.floats(allow_infinity=False)
    ),
    index=indexes(
        elements=st.sampled_from(date_index),  
        min_size=10,
        unique=True
    ),
)

df_example = df_strategy.example()
df_example = df_example.sort_index()

print(df_example)

which gives you
                     sec1           sec2           sec3
2023-12-29 -1.112537e-308  -1.175494e-38   1.100000e+00
2024-01-01  1.797693e+308  -2.000010e+00            NaN
2024-01-02   9.007199e+15  1.797693e+308            NaN
2024-01-03  -3.333333e-01  1.797693e+308  -3.402823e+38
2024-01-04  -2.220446e-16   1.175494e-38            NaN
2024-01-05  -6.229096e+15   1.000000e+07            NaN
2024-01-08 -3.141440e-215 -1.797693e+308  -3.333333e-01
2024-01-09            NaN -8.235561e-109  -2.000010e+00
2024-01-10            NaN -1.797693e+308 -2.225074e-311
2024-01-11  -1.000000e+07   2.220446e-16   1.048046e+16


Well, using .example() was just to show how the dataframe may look like. I am going to use the resulting dataframe in unit tests. That is, I would like the generated dataframe being sorted already. By the way, I could easily have my example index sorted the way you did by just appending .sort_index().
